# how to register microsoft.HDinsight ? on microsoft azure

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

i created a free **Microsoft azure** account, and when i wanted to work with **Microsoft.HDInsight** to create **my spark cluster** i found that it's **Not Registered**, is there a way to **register** Microsoft.HDInsight. (i didn't use any credit from my credit card) but microsoft azure allow 200,00 $US i think.

im lost if anybody know on that domain i highly would appriciate any help :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGXLZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure resource provider named `Microsoft.HDInsight` is registered in your subscription.

***Note:*** You must have permission to do the `/register/action` operation for the resource provider. The permission is included in the Contributor and Owner roles.

Steps to register resource provider in Azure Portal:

1. Select your subscription
2. Under "Settings", select "Resource Providers"
3. Search for `Microsoft.HDInsight`
4. Click on "Register".

[image]