# is amazon EMR cluster avaliable on the free subscribtion trial?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

im new to using clusters . i have a pyspark program on jupyter notebook and i want to deploy it on a cluster.

the two tutorials i found were using **microsoft azure** and **amazone EMR** .
i tried **microsoft azure** and the free subscribtion doesn't include the ability to create one 'if i follow the tutorial' as answred on this question [how to register microsoft.HDinsight ? on microsoft azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72199506/how-to-register-microsoft-hdinsight-on-microsoft-azure) .

So now i want to try  **amazone EMR** and see if it's avaliable for free, or else how much it cost to deploy a small pyspark program from jupyter-notebook to **amazone EMR cluster** .

thank's for your time , i would highely appriciate any help :)

Comment: How much data do you need to scan?

Comment: not too much just a code that uses few functions of spark , applied on matrices from 700x50 to 4000x500 stored on a text file

Answer (score 1):

A free Spark cluster with one node and 15GB of RAM is available with the **Databricks Community Edition**.

*Create a Databricks community edition user:*

Go to:
[Databricks Community Edition](https://community.cloud.databricks.com/login.html)

Click on sign-up

Click on Get Started in the community edition section

You will get a link to your email to create a password for your user

[Databricks Community Edition FAQ](https://databricks.com/product/faq/community-edition)